# Which regex to find a set of numbers?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having troubles finding a regex that can retrieve the numbers `989552` in
`/boards/989552-lettersandnumbers-morelettersandnumbers`

What I'm searching in particular is can I retrieve what stands between `/boards/` and the first `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/boards/(\d+)-
```

Should store the numbers in the first match group.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.*/(\d+)-` as `.*` is greedy it will match upto the last `/`:

```
$string = "/boards/989552-dgw25235-42352gdsgw";

echo preg_match('#.*/(\d+)-#',$string,$match);

echo $match[1];

>>> 989552
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an annotated solution.

```
<?php // RAY_temp_user1722791.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*
I'm having troubles finding a regex that can retrieve the numbers 989552 in /boards/989552-lettersandnumbers-morelettersandnumbers

What I'm searching in particular is can I retrieve what stands between /boards/ and the first -?
*/

// A REGULAR EXPRESSION
$rgx
= '#'         // REGEX DELIMITER
. '/boards/'  // THE SEARCH STRING
. '('         // START A GROUP
. '\d+'       // SOME DIGITS
. ')'         // END OF THE GROUP
. '-'         // THE DASH
. '#'         // REGEX DELIMITER
;

// A TEST STRING
$str = 'in /boards/989552-lettersandnumbers';

// PEFORM THE MATCH
preg_match($rgx, $str, $mat);

// FIND THE NUMBERS IN THE FIRST MATCHED GROUP
var_dump($mat[1]);
```

I find it much easier to understand regular expressions when I write them out in vertical notation like this.